# Loopback Update property Array of Object

Tags: arrays, mongodb, loopback

I'm use loopback and mongodb. 
Right now I have a Model and one of its property type is array of object.
The document in `mongo` will look like this

```
{
  "id": "123123213",
  "name": "Some Name",
  "colors": [{
    "colorId": "1"
    "colorName: "Red"
  }, {
    "colorId": "2",
    "colorName: "Blue"
  }]
}
```

Now i have a requirements to querying update and delete specific object in colors array. Let say i need to update the `colorName` only in `colorId` 2 to Green.
And delete the Color object which the `colorId` is 2.

How to achieve this in loopback? 
Please advise !
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In mongo CLI, you can use `$` (positional) to update matching element from an embedded array document

update

```
> db.colors.update({"colors.colorId" :"2"}, {$set : {"colors.$.colorName" : "Green"}})
```

use `$pull` to delete

```
> db.colors.update({}, {$pull : {"colors" : {"colorId" : "2"}}})
```

Comment: I can do the query in Mongo CLI, but can't do the query in loopback.

After do some research, as stated here, https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb

I need to set `allowExtendedOperators = true` first.

Thank you so much !

Comment: how do you add push a new object to the array of object in loopback without using the $push ? ( in this case how do add a new object to the colors array ) ? any help would be appreciated .

Comment: can we do this using loopback core API?

Comment: @ManishBalodia yes we can, use this code instead `YourModel.updateAll({"colors.colorId":"2"}, {{"$set": {"colors.$.colorName": "Green"}}})`.

But dont forget to set `"allowExtendedOperators": true` in your datasource.json first